# Script not work after redirect in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, assets

I have a clear button on my page with coffee script

html

```
<div class="containerNew">
<%= form_for @customer, :url => customers_path do |f| %>
<table id="createNewCustomer">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Input</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">
            <%= f.label :machine_id, "Error Machine:" %>
        </td>
        <td class="content">
            <%= select("customer", "machine_id", Machine.all.collect {|m| [ m.name, m.id ] }, { include_blank: false }) %>  
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">
            <%= f.label :error_info, "Error Info:" %>
        </td>
        <td class="content">
            <%= f.text_area :error_info %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="bottomBtnArea">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" , class:"button btn btn-primary" %>
    <input type="button" name="clear" value="clear" id="clearBtn" class="btn btn-default">
</div>
<% end %>
```

coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#clearBtn').click ->
    $("#customer_machine_id").get(0).selectedIndex = 0
    $("textarea").val("")
```

It works well when I directly access this page's url which is `localhost:3000/customers/new`

But it can't work when I use the nav link to access this page

```
<%= link_to "Add", new_customer_path %>
```

I use chrome to debug my script, it seems that it didn't go into the function block when I use nav to access this page and then click the clear button. Script file seems not being loaded. I couldn't figure out why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely because of Turbolinks, a Rails feature which does some magical caching and prevents jQuery's page-load trigger from working properly. This question has been answered before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links) for example) – the solution is to add a trigger to load your JS functions on Turbolinks's load events, rather than jQuery's usual `$(document).ready` hook. Assuming you are using Rails 5 this should do it:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $('#clearBtn').click ->
      $("#customer_machine_id").get(0).selectedIndex = 0
      $("textarea").val("")
```

For more information, have a look at the [turbolinks documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#running-javascript-when-a-page-loads).

Comment: thks, this worked for me. Does it mean turbolinks preload the pages in the nav link so I should use the turbolinks way to find out if these page is fully loaded instead of jQuery way?

Comment: basically, yes. It's worth reading up on how Turbolinks actually works, but the way they describe it is in their documentation "When you follow a link, Turbolinks automatically fetches the page, swaps in its <body>, and merges its <head>, all without incurring the cost of a full page load." – this can magically make a simple Rails app feel more like a modern JS-driven single-page application, but does have a few surprises as you have discovered!

Answer (score 1):

Update: turbolink is now just turbo, so in new projects you need `turbo:load` instead.

```js
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", () => {
    console.log("turbo loaded");
});
```

Comment: Works in Rails 7. Thank you for sharing.